# Resource for fmt tag library not getting loaded in footer JSP

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, tld, msgfmt

I have 3 JSP with me. header.jsp, center.jsp and footer.jsp. Together they form a landing page.Each of them gets executed in sequence as provided above.

Now am trying to use fmt tld to show some static content on my site.

My code in header.jsp has

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
....
....
<fmt:requestEncoding value="UTF-8" />
<fmt:setLocale value="en" scope="session"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="content"/>
<fmt:message key="page.header.text"></fmt:message> //this gets displayed
```

In footer.jsp i have the following:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
....
....
<fmt:message key="page.header.text"></fmt:message>
```

In this case the following is displayed..

```
???page.footer???
```

means its not able to find the property. 
If i define the setters which i added in header in the footer then the message comes properly. But ideally i should not be doing that.. what am i doing wrong here for which the bundle is not getting picked up in the footer?

Comment: Where do you use `page.footer` key in the above code (footer seems to use `page.header.text` as well)? How do you combine header, center, and footer? Please show your center page.

Comment: Its like landing.jsp which has the above 3 jsps included in it..

Comment: So no one has any clue? or more details required?